# pyspark - Dense-Rank ties method first

Tags: pandas, pyspark, rank, dense-rank

Is there a way to apply **dense-rank** in a pyspark data-frame, but when finding a tie, ranking the **tie by first** appearance?

Similarly at Pandas `rank(method='first')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distributed nature of `Spark` prevents implicitly identifying the order of appearance. If you input dataset contains a column like `line_number` or `row_number` then `rank(method='first')` can be achieved.

## Working Example

The following example relies on the dataframe from [`pd.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) with a included `Line_Number` field to have explicit ordering.

The dataframe is repartitioned to simulate random ordering after reading data.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

data = [{"Line_Number": 1, "Animal": "cat", "Number_legs": 4}, {"Line_Number": 2, "Animal": "penguin", "Number_legs": 2},
        {"Line_Number": 3, "Animal": "dog", "Number_legs": 4}, {"Line_Number": 4, "Animal": "spider", "Number_legs": 8},
        {"Line_Number": 5, "Animal": "snake", "Number_legs": None}]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).repartition(8)


window_spec = Window.orderBy(F.col("Number_legs").asc_nulls_last(), F.col("Line_Number"))

df.withColumn("rank", F.when(F.col("Number_legs").isNull(), F.lit(None)).otherwise(F.row_number().over(window_spec))).show()
```

### Output

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+----+
| Animal|Line_Number|Number_legs|rank|
+-------+-----------+-----------+----+
|penguin|          2|          2|   1|
|    cat|          1|          4|   2|
|    dog|          3|          4|   3|
| spider|          4|          8|   4|
|  snake|          5|       null|null|
+-------+-----------+-----------+----+
```